# Unexpected token error when compile a Typescript to Javascript that used to work using ts-node

Tags: typescript

I'm working with a Typescript project that i run using "ts-node".

```
$ ts-node .\src\index.ts
it works =)
```

But I would like to compile it to Javascript. so i ran.

```
$ tsc
$ node .\src\index.js
```

but i got the fallowing error:

```
(node:4392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: \event-monitor\src\models\Alarm.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import BaseEntity from "./BaseEntity";
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
(node:4392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4392) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I dont unserstand why using ts-node runs fine, but using TSC it does not works.

Here is my ts-config file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "types": ["mocha", "chai", "node"],
    "paths": { "@/*": ["src/*"] },
    "lib": ["es5", "es6"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "tests/**/*.ts", "repoTest.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Modules that i'm using:

```
"lodash": "^4.17.11",
"mysql": "^2.17.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
"restify": "^8.3.0",
"sqlite3": "^4.0.6",
"typeorm": "^0.2.16",
"typescript": "^3.0.3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out what happens.

I was using TypeORM which is looking for TS files for its entities.

However in "js mode", i must configure TypeOMR to look after dist/js files instead.

Answer (score 0):

Node doesn't support ES6 modules so you need to import and export modules using the special TyeScript format for CommonJS modules, e.g.

```
export = BaseEntity;
```

and

```
import BaseEntity = require('./BaseEntity');
```

This is documented (not very well) in the [TS handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require)

Comment: But TSC compiler has `"target": "es5"` and `"module": "commonjs"`. It should be able to do the transpile job

Comment: Module commonjs requires you to do the imports this way.